# how to solve invalid types for array subscript error?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to pass a 3D array to function and change it's values. The problem is that I get an error: invalid types 'unsigned char[int]' for array subscript.
Code in main:

```
unsigned char image[height][width][BYTES_PER_PIXEL];
setBlankImage((unsigned char*)image, width, height);
```

Function code:

```
void setBlankImage(unsigned char *image, int width, int height){
    for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < width; ++j){
            image[i][j][2] = 0;
            image[i][j][1] = 0;
            image[i][j][0] = 0;
        }  
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are `height`, `width`, and `BYTES_PER_PIXEL`?

Comment: 1. Variable length arrays are not standard in C++. 2. `unsigned char *image` is not array as the compiler tries to explain.

Comment: width - image width by pixels (100)
height - image height by pixels (100)
BYTES_PER_PIXEL - is a const int that  show, how many bytes are in one pixel (3)

Comment: Your `image` in `setBlankImage` is and `unsigned char*`, yet you are dereferincing it 3 times? How's that supposed to work.

Comment: So, how should I change it, so that it would work?

Comment: You're passing a pointer to a *single* `char`.  There is no guarantee that the pointer *can* be incremented.  With that said, a 2 dimensional array, `operator[][]`, needs to know the capacity of right most dimension in order calculate the address.  So, for a 3d array, the compiler needs to know the compacities of two dimensions.  Thus the compiler is having a hard time calculating the address of `image[i][j][2]`.  You should pass the array using array notation, not by pointer to the first location.

Comment: Another method is to calculate the final address *by hand*.  For example, with a 2d array:  `int * p_location = image + (row * MAX_COLUMNS) + column;`  This can be expanded to 3d array:  `int p_location = image + (i * height) + (j * width) + 2;`  Since your function parameters don't specify the dimensions of the array, you'll have to access locations using the above statements (linear algebra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 methods of passing an array:

1. Using array notation.
2. Using `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>`
3. Pointer to the first location.

Your code is using method 3 above.  Since it's a pointer to a single location, you'll have to adjust the pointer to the appropriate cell using linear algebra (see my comments).

The simplest method is to use `std::vector`.

The first option would work with your code:

```
void setBlankImage(int image[][256][256]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can freely change the type of `image` and its dimensions are known at compile-time, I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, size_t Width, size_t Height, size_t Depth>
using My3DArray = std::array<std::array<std::array<T, Depth>, Height>, Width>;

template <typename T, size_t Width, size_t Height, size_t Depth>
void setBlankImage(My3DArray<T, Width, Height, Depth>& arr, T value = 0){
    for(auto& slice0: arr) {
        for(auto& slice1: slice0) {
            for(auto& elem: slice1) {
                elem = value;
            }
        }  
    }
}

int main()
{
    My3DArray<int, 4, 3, 2> arr;
    arr[0][0][0] = 42;
    std::cout << arr[0][0][0] << std::endl;
    
    try {
        arr.at(3).at(2).at(1) = 43; // OK
        arr.at(3).at(2).at(2) = 44; // Exception
        arr[3][2][2] = 45;          // Good old SEGFAULT
    }
    catch(const std::out_of_range& e) {
        std::cout << "There's even OOB check, sweet!" << std::endl << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, image is declared with type `unsigned char***`:

```
unsigned char image[height][width][BYTES_PER_PIXEL];
```

Here, you cast it to a `unsigned char*` before invoking your function:

```
setBlankImage((unsigned char*)image, width, height);
```

You should change the parameter to be of type unsigned char***.

Comment: The type `char * * *` indicates a *pointer* depth of 3.  The first indicates a pointer to a single location.  The second indicates a pointer to (a pointer to a single location).  The third asterix indicates a pointer to {a pointer to (a pointer to a single location)}.  In other words, passing a pointer to an array of pointers.  The OP's code is represented as consecutive locations in memory, not pointers.